# Swift: Get n numbers of points around a rounded rect / squircle with angle

Tags: swift, swiftui, geometry, rounded-corners

I’m searching for a method that returns a `CGPoint` and `Angle` for each of `n` items around a rounded rect / squircle (I’m aware those shapes are different but suspect they don’t make a relevant visual difference in my case. Therefore I’m searching for the easiest solution).

Something like this:

```
func getCoordinates(of numberOfPoints: Int, in roundedRect: CGRect, with cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> [(CGPoint, Angle)] {
   // ... NO IDEA HOW TO COMPUTE THIS
}
```

My ultimate goal is to draw something like this (points distributed with equal angles):
[image: Image of the simulator app for an Apple Watch]

Unfortunately my math skills are not sufficient.

Comment: You have not defined how points should be distributed. Two simple ways - equal angles and equal distances along perimeter

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @MBo — I’ve updated my question. Looking at the picture and Apples Watchfaces, I think I’m looking for `equal angles`.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode. Used center as `cx, cy`, `w` and `h` as **half**-width and **half**-height, `r` as corner radius.

Calculate angle in side for-loop, add `phase` to start from needed direction (0 from OX axis, Pi/2 from OY axis)

```
for (i = 0..n-1):
    angle = i * 2 * math.pi / n + phase
```

Get unit vector components for this direction and absolute values

```
dx = cos(angle)
dy = sin(angle)
ax = abs(dx)
ay = abs(dy)
```

Find vertical or horizontal for this direction and calculate point relative to center (we work in the first quadrant at this moment):

```
if ax * h > ay * w:
    x = w
    y = w * ay / ax
else:
    y = h
    x = ax * h / ay
```

Now we have to correct result **if** point is in rounded corner:

```
if (x > w - r) and (y > h - r):  
   recalculate x and y as below
```

Here we have to find intersection of the ray with circle arc.

Circle equation

```
(x - (w-r))^2 + (y - (h-r))^2 = r^2
(x - wr)^2 + (y - hr)^2 = r^2   //wr = w - r, hr = h - r
```

Ray equation (`t` is parameter)

```
x = ax * t
y = ay * t
```

Substitute in circle eq:

```
(ax*t - wr)^2 + (ay*t - hr)^2 = r^2
ax^2*t^2 - 2*ax*t*wr + wr^2 + ay^2*t^2 -2*ay*t*hr + hr^2 -r^2 = 0
t^2*(ax^2+ay^2) + t*(-2*ax*wr - 2*ay*hr) + (wr^2 +hr^2 - r^2) = 0
t^2* a +          t* b +                         c            = 0
```

Solve this quadratic equation for unknown `t`, get larger root, and find intersection point substituting `t` into ray equation.

Now we want to put result into correct quadrant:

```
if dx < 0:
    x = -x
if dy < 0:
    y = -y
```

and shift them by center coordinates

```
dx += cx
dy += cy
```

That's all.

Comment: This is a great answer and explains the math very well. I have borrowed your knowledge and created a gist that builds a SwiftUI View with a function returning an array with points and angles.
https://gist.github.com/Enie/ef563325a84923be3808fa6c2810922d

Comment: @Enie Seems you calculate point H insead of K (https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8WtZ.png). Looks like admissible approximation for this task

Comment: Yes I wasn't quite sure how to solve the quadratic equation programmatically, so I tried with vector combination. Somehow at my first try it resulted in rather skewed results in the rounded corners with long rectangles. But after changing some code to what you proposed I saw quite sufficient results.